# In a classic ASP application, is it better to use a session or cookie for cross-page data persistence?

Tags: asp-classic, session-variables, client-side-data

I have inherited a fix on a classic ASP application where we want to store some user session-specific data to persist across page loads/their session, and need a bit of a refresher.

In the past I have simply used Session variables - ie. `Session("SomeVar") = SomeVal`.

In IIS on the production box, I noticed that ASP / Session Properties / Enable Session State = false.  Setting this to True allowed me to successfully begin using session variables.

I don't want to consume any more resources than necessary on the server.  In the past, I believe that I was under the delusional misconception that session variables in classic ASP  were stored on the client side.  Revisiting this now - the data is retained on the server side.

The string I am saving is a GUID, for roughly 3000 connected clients.

What kind of server impact am I looking at if I implement this, and would using client-side cookies be a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets analyse this a bit, a GUID takes about 40 characters as a string hence in Unicode thats 80 bytes,  lets call it 100 bytes.  100 * 3000 = 300KB.  Can server spare 300K for this?  I think the server already in trouble if the answer were no.

However there are other impacts to enable session state.  When sessions are enabled ASP adds its own cookie to the client which in size terms is probably equivalent to the one you would need if you were storing your GUID as cookie instead of in the session.  Its worth noting that this session ID stored in the cookie uses an algorithm which some say is more predictable (I haven't got any evidence of that myself).  Hence if you are using the GUID as some form of authorization then storing the GUID as cookie directly may be better.

There is a further significant change that happens when Session state is enabled.  ASP requests from a client must be processed serially, the server will not process multiple requests from the same client in parallel.  This is because the Session object is single threaded and since each request from a client needs access to it the requests cannot be processed at the same time.

That last point could have significant impact on the existing behaviour and performance that a client sees especially if AJAX techniques, multiple IFrames or other techniques which result in simultaneous ASP requests being sent to the server are being used.

Hence for the requirement you have my choice would be to store the GUID in a cookie and leave session state turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple servers/server farm? If so you might run into trouble using Session if you load balancer is not set to be "sticky" and send you to the same server each time. Can me a real headache to debug so becareful.